# how to search for any value in the document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to search for all value present without specifying key explicitly. Is it possible with this type of schema? If so, how can I write my query. I tried to write query with other refs but I am unable to write without specifying key for each.

```
const pschema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, // combine by id
    ref: "users" //existing model reference
  },
  company: {
    empNo: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    status: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },...
  },
  personal: {
    gender: {
      type: String
    },
    dob: {
      type: Date
    },...
  },
  skills: {
    type: [String],
    required: true
  },
  experience: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      company: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      location: {
        type: String
      }...
    }
  ],
  education: [
    {
      school: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      degree: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      specialization: {
        type: String
      },..
    }
  ],
  social: {
    twitter: {
      type: String
    },
    facebook: {
      type: String
    },
    linkedin: {
      type: String
    },...
  }
});
```

For example: If i give linkedin url if should search in social-linkedin and same if i give c it should search in skills array

Comment: so, in here you have to form the query first, 
say you want to saech for linkedin url: `<MODEL>.find({"social.linkedin":"<sme linkedin url>"}).exec()`,
now say you want to search for skill,: `<MODEL>.find({skills:"<some skill>"}).select({"skills.$":1}).exec(...)`

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty Thanks for addressing. But i want to query " user input"- which can be anywhere in empNo,skills,dob,company etc... So basically i will not know what is the object.key. how can I address such scenarios